# get currently showed author ID in theme functions.php

Tags: theme-development

I am adding a filter in my theme `functions.php`. Let's say i named the filter function `my_filter_function` which is defined in `functions.php`.

When i visit a author page like `/author/arandomauthor` i want to get author id inside `my_filter_function`.

But following code give me empty string though it works inside `author.php` template.

```
$user_id = get_query_var('author');
```

Comment: which hook are you attaching it to? maybe you are adding it to one that runs before query vars are available

Comment: it is `wpcf7_mail_components` hook from contact form 7

Comment: please add your function code